# JodaTime Serialization issue

Tags: java, jodatime, json4s

I have an existing app using `Java JodaTime`. However, after upgrading to the latest `json4s-core` library 3.6.0-M3, I'm getting the following errors converting date strings with a timezone to a Date.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No instant converter found for type: org.json4s.ext.DateParser$ZonedInstant
```

It happens when I write a custom `DateTime` serializer with fallback for multiple formats:

```
 case JString(s) ⇒ Try(dateTimeFormat.parseDateTime(s)).getOrElse(new DateTime(DateParser.parse(s, format)))
```

Example string causing the issue: 2018-05-02T21:43:29Z

I made sure I'm using jodatime 2.9.2 and the matching json4s-ext lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave my answer in case someone runs into a similar issue. I realized that since I'm overriding the default `DateTime` serializer, I needed to make the following change to my custom serializer to deal with  `ZonedInstant`

```
case JString(s) ⇒ Try(dateTimeFormat.parseDateTime(s)).getOrElse({
    val zonedInstant = DateParser.parse(s, format)
    new DateTime(zonedInstant.instant, DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(zonedInstant.timezone))
  })
```